# How to collect statistics on how many times a keyboard shortcut I use?

Tags: osx, productivity, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to collect the statistics on how many times a keyboard shortcut I use. I need this because I want to make some analyses on productivity improvement.

I use OsX.