# Statistics about most frequent actions in Windows

Tags: windows, logs, productivity, optimization

I would like to optimize my use of Windows by first analyzing what I do most frequently: what programs I open, what shortcuts I use, where I click with the mouse, etc.

**Is there a software that monitors this activity and give me statistics? I will use this information to create new shortcuts, bookmarks, etc.**

This question is similar to [How to collect statistics on how many times a keyboard shortcut I use?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7053/how-to-collect-statistics-on-how-many-times-a-keyboard-shortcut-i-use) but that question refers only to osx and only to shortcuts.

Comment: For open programs and webpages, you can use [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/), but it does not track mouse clicks